# AWS Lambda Create alias

Tags: jenkins, aws-lambda, alias

According AWS documentation I can create a new lambda function alias like:
 `aws lambda create-alias \
--region us-west-2 \
--function-name helloworld \
--description "sample alias" \
--function-version "\$LATEST" \
--name DEV \
--profile adminuser`

As I understand, this command basically deploys code to latest lambda alias. So I believe it becomes active as soon as I deploy it. But I would to test it before make it live. My question is, what is the easiest way to put it in an intermediate phase so it could wait until my Jenkins tests are complete and then activate it? Should I create another function-version like $PRE_LATEST or so?

Comment: *"As I understand, this command basically deploys code to latest lambda alias."*  This sets the `DEV` alias to point to the same version that `$LATEST` references at the time the command is issued.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command you list will create an alias named `DEV` which points at the `$LATEST` Lambda code. You can think of `$LATEST` as a special alias itself which is always pointing at the most recently uploaded function code. What this means is that if you upload new function code for the Lambda, `DEV` will now point at that instead of where it was when you ran the `create-alias` command. That's not usually what we want.

If you would like to create an alias to a specific version of the Lambda, you need to first publish a version:

```
$ aws lambda publish-version --function-name helloworld
```

This command will create a numbered version of the `helloworld` Lambda function from its current `$LATEST` state. The output of the command will be some JSON which includes a version number string like: `"Version": "2",`.

You can then use create an alias pointing to this specific version:

```
$ aws lambda create-alias --function-name helloworld --name DEV --function-version 2
```

Neither the alias nor the version will change when you upload new function code later. In fact, the version `2` of the Lambda will never change at all. The alias `DEV` can be updated later to point at a different version that you have published:

```
$ aws lambda update-alias --function-name helloworld --name DEV --function-version 3
```

For your use case, if you'd like to upload function code to Lambda and test it before pushing it live, I would suggest creating a `LIVE` alias which your production services use. Your flow would then be something like:

1. Upload new function code. This updates `$LATEST`.
2. Publish version. This copies `$LATEST` to a number `N`.
3. Update `DEV` alias to point at version `N`.
4. Test and approve the changes.
5. Update `LIVE` alias to point at version `N`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that was very helpful, sorry for late answer I was in Thanksgiving vacation with a limited internet access.

Comment: Is it possible to update the Alias from Console? Can only find "Create new Alias" , and it will throw error upon same alias name.

Comment: @Vineeth I haven't checked recently to confirm, but yes historically I have never been able to find a way to update an existing alias in the web console. I've always either deleted/recreated or used the CLI instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above answer you would be probably uploading the zip file to the lambda with all the dependencies and then publish a new version and then map that version with an existing alias.
Wrote a quick shell script to do this

```
# Remove zip file if already exit
rm index.zip
# Creating zip file
zip -r index.zip *
# Update lambda function, assuming the name of the current directory is same as the lambda function
lambdaName=${PWD##*/}
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $lambdaName --zip-file fileb://index.zip
# Publish version
aws lambda publish-version --function-name $lambdaName
# Get latest version
version=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name $lambdaName --description "updated via cli" --query Version | bc)
# Map alias to latest version this can be LIVE or TEST as per the above answer
aws lambda update-alias --function-name $lambdaName \--function-version $version --name TEST|LIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question -
**Is it possible to update the Alias from Console?** Can only find "Create new Alias" , and it will throw error upon same alias name. – Vineeth Feb 16 '18 at 9:15

Yes it is possible to change the Version that a lambda Alias points to from the console, but it's well hidden by the abysmal Lambda UI...

Click on the Alias dropdown, then select the Alias you want to change (e.g. Prod).

The bottom (hidden!!!) half of the page entitled Alias will update, and give you  a dropdown where you can change both the Alias Description and also the Version that the selected Alias points to.

Only when you change one of those fields, is the Save button enabled.